# .Net service for remotely collecting files

Tags: c#, service, .net-4.0, remote-access

I'm being tasked with creating a service to remotely(on the network still) access other PCs via either their computer name or IP address and collect log files from a pre-determined folder on the hour. This has to be done in the background, with a system tray icon for allowing user to bring up menus for changing frequency of log collection, change computer collecting from, and save location. For whatever reason I'm having a hard time finding resources for getting started, I'm not quite sure what to search for but I want to find out how to set up a service to allow the communication/remote access to directories on another computer in it's network. I apologize if the answer is obvious, this is my first ever experience with any sort of remoting between computers from my own software, but if anyone has resources or links to spare I'd appreciate it!

NOTE: I've checked out [Use .NET Remoting to transfer a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104827/use-net-remoting-to-transfer-a-file) but it's not clear if that is helpful or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need remoting. All you need to do is set up a share on the remote computer so that you can access its files over the network. So, for example, if the remote machine is called SITHLORD and the directory is C:\SomeApp\LogFiles. . .

First, on the SITHLORD machine, make sure that file sharing is enabled, and then share that directory. Call it LogFiles.

On the machine that will run the service, you should be able to access those files from the command line by typing this command at the command prompt:

```
dir \\SITHLORD\LogFiles
```

If you get an error, you'll have to resolve that before you can go any further.

After you have the ability to view the files from the command line, then you can write C# code to scan the directory and read the files. All of the standard .NET file operations (`Directory.GetFiles`, `File.Open`, etc) will work with network paths. So you could copy the file "MyLogFile1.log" in that directory with:

```
File.Copy(@"\\SITHLORD\LogFiles\MyLogFile1.log", @".\Archive\SithLord\MyLogFile1.log");
```

That said, what you're talking about doing sounds like it's something you're better off doing with a PowerShell script and a scheduled task, with a C# program to alter the configuration of the script and modify the task configuration. Writing a Windows service to do this seems like overkill.

But if you do decide to write a Windows service, all you need is simple file operations.